# Start a function when mouseover and stop it when mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, mouseover

I want the function mozaic to start when mouseover and stop when mouseleave. The first one works properly. Here's the code:

```
$('#name').mouseover(function() {
    var mozaic = setInterval(mosaic, 150);
});

$('#name').mouseout(function() {
    //code...
});

function mosaic() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#name').addClass('shadowLasure');
    }, 0);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#name').removeClass('shadowLasure');
        $('#name').addClass('shadowPink');
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#name').removeClass('shadowPink');
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: doesn't make sense. You have an interval timer set. Objective is not clear at all

Comment: What if the user moves the mouse into #name and then stops. should mosaic be moving? the moment the mouse continues to move once it has entered #name it would stop by your requirements, making the mouseover somewhat pointless.

Comment: but, the mouse is going to be moving when the mouseover happens, unless the user is good enough to be able to stop their mouse the moment the enter happens and not move it another pixel..

Comment: you need a far better description of expected behavior for anyone to help with this. It almost sounds like you haven't thought this through thoroughly

Comment: then you want to use mouseout or mouseleave...not mousemove

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this.

You need the variable accessible in both functions so it needs to be declared outside those functions and then defined inside the first one and use `clearInterval()` to cancel an existing interval

```
var timer;
$('#name').mouseenter(function() {
   timer = setInterval(mosaic, 150);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Comment: Also, you should explain the problems.  OP clearly doesn't have a solid handle on JS, and what you've done clearly works, but why? What's different? What was wrong?

Comment: @KevinB agree, those are ones i usually use...ws being lazy doing copy/pste

Comment: @kinduser In regards to what?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Kevin B, the mouse will move when over the text and prevent the animation from being visible.

But to achieve what you have asked for, use the following

```
var mozaic;

$('#name').mouseover(function() {
    mozaic = setInterval(mosaic, 150);
});

$(document).mousemove(function() {
   clearInterval(mozaic);
});
```

Note, that the `mosaic` variable has to be global, so that the *mousemove* function has access to it. Initializing it inside the *mouseover* function will limit its **scope** to within that function.

Maybe to achieve what you want (effect wise) try to use *mouseout* on the text.

```
$('#name').mouseout(function() {
    clearInterval(mosaic);
}
```

Comment: can't use `var mosaic` is same name as function

Comment: the function is actually called `mosaic` with a **s**. The var is called `mozaic`with a  **z**. Not beautiful but I just adapted to the names in his CodePen Example. It worked by the way.

Comment: @JHolub based on my misread it should now be obvious to you now not to name things so closely that it is easy to glance over minor minor differences...just asking for maintanability issues

Comment: Of course it was obvious for me to begin with. As said, I just adapted to the names the question author gave them in his CodePen example.